# Cross thread update of shared/static datasource not catched

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, datagridview

I have a shared/static *DataTable* which can be accessed throughout the application.
On a *Form* i have a *DataGridView* bound to a *DataView* of the *DataTable*.
My problem is that a cross-thread update of the *DataTable* is not catched by the *DataGridView*, although the underlying datasource (DataView) is updated.

I've tried the update, invalidate, refresh and resetbindings methods of the *DataGridView*, but still no rows added, removed or updated.

```
'The following example requires:
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Friend WithEvents DataGridView1 As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
'Friend WithEvents Button1 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
'Friend WithEvents Button2 As System.Windows.Forms.Button
'Friend WithEvents BackgroundWorker1 As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Class Form1

    Shared Sub New()
        Repository = New DataTable()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Me.view = New DataView(Repository)
        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.view
    End Sub

    'Updates the DataGridView correctly.
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Using table As DataTable = GetUpdatedDataTable()
            SyncLock Repository
                Repository.Merge(table)
            End SyncLock
        End Using
    End Sub

    'Do NOT update the DataGridView correctly (cross-thread)
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If (Not Me.BackgroundWorker1.IsBusy) Then
            Me.BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Using table As DataTable = GetUpdatedDataTable()
            SyncLock Repository
                Repository.Merge(table)
            End SyncLock
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Me.DataGridView1.Update()
        Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
        Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate(False)
        Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate(True)
        Me.DataGridView1.ResetBindings()
        MsgBox(Me.view.Count)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetUpdatedDataTable() As DataTable
        Dim table As New DataTable("TEST")
        table.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn() {New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)), New DataColumn("TEXT", GetType(String))})
        table.Rows.Add(Repository.Rows.Count, String.Format("Row #{0}", Repository.Rows.Count))
        table.AcceptChanges()
        Return table
    End Function

    Public Shared Repository As DataTable
    Private ReadOnly view As DataView

End Class'
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure you should not be using `Repository` as the object for SyncLock.

Comment: Maybe, but why do you think so? According to msdn "the SyncLock statement ensures that multiple threads do not execute the same statements at the same time".

Comment: **Every** example of using SyncLock I have seen uses a dedicated Object for it. Maybe having a synclock on Repository stops the UI thread from being able to access Repository when it needs to, but that's only a wild guess.

Comment: I really appreciate your help Andrew, but dropping the SyncLoc didn't do any difference. It seems like some of the "changed handles" never reaches the DataGridView. The DataView is update correctly, but no DataGridViewRows are added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this question is soon to celebrate it's 1st "birthday", what wouldn't be better than to give it a final answer. The reason why the `DataGridView` isn't updated is because the `DataView.ListChanged` events (which the DGV hooks) are raised on the worker thread and not the UI thread.

**Option 1**

Do the merging on the UI thread.

```
Me.Invoke(Sub() Repository.Merge(table))
```

Of course, this will freeze the application until the merging has completed.

**Option 2**

Subclass the `DataView` and give it the ability to raise the `ListChanged` event when needed.

```
Public Class DataViewEx
    Inherits DataView

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(table As DataTable)
        MyBase.New(table)
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(table As DataTable, rowFilter As String, sort As String, rowState As DataViewRowState)
        MyBase.New(table, rowFilter, sort, rowState)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Refresh()
        Me.OnListChanged(New ListChangedEventArgs(ListChangedType.Reset, -1))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now, once the worker has completed its task, all one have to do is call the `Refresh` method and the `DataGridView` are *"back in sync"* with the `DataView`.

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    Me.view.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should instead of Refresh, try the following:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
            Me.DataGridView1.Update()
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
            Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Repository           
            Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate(False)
            Me.DataGridView1.Invalidate(True)
            Me.DataGridView1.ResetBindings()
            MsgBox(Me.view.Count)
        End Sub
```